How can I fix a library add syntax error?
I am getting error like this
Error Message:
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.implementation: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
For example, I need to use the code like this:<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
What should I do for the error?
implementation(files("libs\\gradle-wrapper.jar"))
implementation(files("libs\\slide.jar"))
implementation(files("libs\\imagecropper.jar"))

When I add it this way, I cannot use it as I stated.

You seem to be using kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts)
in order to import something, you do it in this way:
implementation("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0")
not
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0' as we used to do before (when using build.gradle)
